# joining two large rdds always ends up spilling

Tags: scala, join, apache-spark, rdd

I have two rdds to be joined on their common key values.

```
val emp = sc.textFile("text1.txt").map(line => (line.split("\t")(5),line.split("\t")(0))).distinct() // 400 million // 9 GB
val emp_new = sc.textFile("text2.txt").map(line => (line.split("\t")(3),line.split("\t")(1))).distinct() // 4 million   // 110 KB
```

MY SPARK CONFIGURATION:

First I set in my intellij: -Xmx64G

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("abdulhay").setMaster("local[*]").set("spark.shuffle.spill", "true")
      .set("spark.shuffle.memoryFraction", "0.6").set("spark.storage.memoryFraction", "0.4")
      .set("spark.executor.memory","40g")
      .set("spark.driver.memory","40g")

val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
```

MY COMPUTER:

```
128GB RAM & 24 CORES
```

So far I have tried two different options:

FIRST:

```
val partitioner = new HashPartitioner(500)
val empp = emp.partitionBy(partitioner)
val emp_neww = emp_new.partitionBy(partitioner)

var joinRDD = empp.join(emp_neww);

val kkk = joinRDD.map(line => (line._2,1)).reduceByKey((a, b) => a + b)

kkk.foreach(println)
```

In this approach I have tried to implement what is suggested here:[How can I efficiently join a large rdd to a very large rdd in spark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31392261/how-can-i-efficiently-join-a-large-rdd-to-a-very-large-rdd-in-spark)

However, on my UI spark still partition the rdds as default. It partitions emp with 287 and the other with 4. And after a while spark starts spilling and it lasts hours.

SECOND:

```
val emp_newBC = sc.broadcast(emp_new.groupByKey.collectAsMap)

val joined = emp.mapPartitions(iter => for {
      (k, v1) <- iter
      v2 <- emp_newBC.value.getOrElse(k, Iterable())
    } yield (s"$v1-$v2", 1)).repartition(sc.defaultParallelism * 500)

val olsun = joined.reduceByKey((a,b) => a+b)

    olsun.foreach(println)
```

In this case I have tried broadcast variable since emp_new is around 100 KB. However again after a while sparks started to spill lasting forever. Besides, I am not sure if i am applying the repartitioning? Finally I have also tried to increase partition number from 500 to 5000 but it did not work out.

So how should I approach this issue? Or is it worthless to strive with such computer features?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're data is larger than available memory, and it looks thats the case, there is no way to avoid spilling to disk.

Comment: Even if the data is not larger than available memory, joined data might be much larger than it. For example in my case number of rows resulting from join is about 1.5 trillion. So how shall i predict how much memory i need?

Comment: I have tried the same codes in a server with 128 gb memory and 8 cores. I edited the post.. Still spilling.

Comment: @user3198674 would you report how did you proceed with your simple experiment? and what was the final result? this will help others in the small spark community to learn.

Comment: @TNM you can check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33177475/is-it-possible-to-join-two-rdds-values-to-avoid-expensive-shuffling